# Proving the Non-Emptiness of an Intersection of Neighborhoods in Euclidean k-Space

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

This is obviously true but I can't figure out how to prove it:

Let $r>0$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$.

Let $k\in\{1,2, \ldots\}$.

Let $a\in\mathbb{R}^k$.

Let $p\in\mathbb{R}^k$ satisfty $|p-a|=r$

where $|x|$ is the Euclidian norm $|x| := \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2}, \quad x := (x_1,\ldots,x_k)\in\mathbb{R}^k$.

Prove the following:
$$
N_\varepsilon(p) \cap N_r(a) \setminus\{p\} \neq\varnothing
$$
or, equivalently, identify a $q \in \mathbb{R}^k$ which satisfies:
$$
|q-a| <r
    \quad\text{ and }\quad
    0< |q-p| < \varepsilon.
$$

Preferably, I would love to be able to identify a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$, defined in terms of $r,\varepsilon,$ etc., such that the above is satisfies by every $q\in A$, is that is possible.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The norm that you define is not the Euclidean. You either need to change the definition, or not call it Euclidean. For that matter I am not convinced that it is a norm at all, looks like $|(-1,1)|=0$ which shouldn't be for any norm. (Given it is not a norm, it also becomes unclear what you mean by $N_\varepsilon(p)$.)

Comment: My bad, you're right. That was just a careless mistake on my part. I believe it's fixed now.

Comment: Draw a picture for $k=2$. That should help you figure out how to produce some point $q$ satisfying those conditions.

Comment: Take a point $q$ on the line segment from $p$ to $a$ that is distance $\min\{\frac{\varepsilon}2, \frac r2\}$ from $p$.

Comment: I like your idea @Mirko , and sure enough such a q satisfies what we want it to satisfy, but what concerns me is how do we prove that such a q exists? Here is my work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kB5WggVPW3Ez3SGllG53xJzvlvvVMtxT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Again, it is intuitively extremely obvious that such a q as you suggest exists, yet for some reason I am failing to develop an argument by contradiction (that is my instinct) that such a q exists. Does any one have any suggestions? The file to which I gave a link is a PDF of my scratch work.

Comment: huh, ... how do we prove that points on a line segment do exists ... distance from one endpoint that is less than the length of the line segment? It might have something to do with Euclidean geometry, intersection of a circle (or a sphere, not a ball) with a line segment ... but I can't remember that far back :)

Comment: Right, sorry if I am not being clear. I suppose my question is this: Certainly, **if** 1) $d(a,q) + d(q,p) = r$ (q is on the line segment which you say) *and* 2) $q = \min\{\frac{\varepsilon}{2}, \frac{r}{2} \}$ **then** this $q$ solves the problem. The fact that the points on the line segment exist is clear. In other words, the fact that $\exists$ a $q$ which satisfies (1) is clear. How, then, do we prove that there exists a $q$ which satisfies **both** (1) and (2)? This is, considering $\varepsilon >0$ is given and could be much smaller than $r$.

Answer (score 0):

Follow up: Here is a potential justification, which begs the question: **is the following any less of a hand wave than just saying "clearly $\mathbf{N_\varepsilon(p) \cap N_r(a) \setminus\{p\}\neq\varnothing}$?"**

Solution:

Assume for the sake of a contradiction that  $N_\varepsilon(p) \cap N_r(a) \setminus\{p\}=\varnothing$.

Let $\delta = \inf\{d(x,y)\geq 0 : x\in N_\varepsilon(p), \hspace{1mm} y \in N_r(a) \}.$ That the infimum of this set exists is assured, since this set is bounded below by zero. Moreover, the case $\delta =0$ is not of concern for our argument. We then have:

$$
d(a,p) = \underbrace{\varepsilon + \delta}_{\geq \varepsilon + 0 > 0} + r > 0+r,
$$

or $d(a,p) > r$, which contradicts our assumption that $d(a,p)=r$.

This contradiction if $N_\varepsilon(p) \cap N_r(a) \setminus\{p\}=\varnothing$ shows that we must have $N_\varepsilon(p) \cap N_r(a) \setminus\{p\}\neq\varnothing$.

Is the line "$d(a,p) = \varepsilon + \delta + r$" too much of a hand wave? It feels unjustified.

P.S. I hope I did not seem like I didn't put any effort into this question before asking. What can I do in the future to improve the quality of my question?